# Using asyncio with pandas.to_sql() running out of memory

Tags: python, pandas, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm trying to concurrently fetch data from an API and save to table in SQL server. But I'm running into a memory issue. I believe the reason is because I `await` fetch tasks to complete first before I `await` save tasks. Below is my code:

```
import asyncio
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd
import itertools


async def save_to_land(transactions, table_name, conn_object, semaphore):

    def process_and_save(transactions):
        df = pl.DataFrame(transactions, infer_schema_length=2000)
        # some processing with polars
        #  ...
        df.to_pandas().to_sql(table_name, conn_object, if_exists='append', index=False)

    if transactions:
        async with semaphore:
            # run sync code in separate thread to not block async event loop
            await asyncio.to_thread(process_and_save, transactions)

async def get_transactions(api, practice_id, year, incremental, with_deleted, date_modified, semaphore):
    async with semaphore:
        transactions = await api.get_transactions(practice_id, year, incremental=incremental, with_deleted=with_deleted, date_modified=date_modified)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        return transactions
    
async def get_transactions_and_save_to_land(api, practice_ids, table_name, conn_object, start_year, end_year, incremental, with_deleted, date_modified, batch_size=100000):

    # for concurrent api requests
    sem1 = asyncio.Semaphore(4)
    # for concurrent db writes
    sem2 = asyncio.Semaphore(3)

    if not incremental:
        get_tasks = []
        for practice_id, year in itertools.product(practice_ids, range(start_year, end_year + 1)):
            task = asyncio.create_task(get_transactions(api, practice_id, year, incremental=incremental, with_deleted=with_deleted, date_modified=date_modified, semaphore=sem1))
            get_tasks.append(task)
        
        results = await asyncio.gather(*get_tasks) 
        
        save_tasks = []
        batch_transactions = []
        for transactions in results:
            batch_transactions.extend(transactions)
            if len(batch_transactions) >= batch_size:
                task = asyncio.create_task(save_to_land(batch_transactions, table_name, conn_object, semaphore=sem2))
                save_tasks.append(task)
                batch_transactions = []

        # for any remaining transactions
        if batch_transactions:
            save_tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(save_to_land(batch_transactions, table_name, conn_object, semaphore=sem2)))

        await asyncio.gather(*save_tasks)
```

How can I get around this? Can someone more experienced with asyncio please advise?
Also, please note that I'm using `asyncio.to_thread()` to run `pandas.to_sql()` portion since it is blocking code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are reading all your results before writing anything.  If you don't have enough memory to hold all your results, then you're going to get an overflow.

You might want to consider asyncio.as_completed.  The end of your code would just be:

```
        # delete results = asyncio.gather(....)
        save_tasks = []
        batch_transactions = []
        for transactions in asyncio.as_completed(get_tasks):
            batch_transactions.extend(transactions)
            ... rest of code as written ...
```

---

An alternate solution that also solves another problem.

Instead of having your reader `return transactions`, it should just put them onto a queue: `q.put(transactions)`.  You can decide whether `q` is a global variable or you pass it as an argument.

You would then continue:

```
    task_count = len(get_tasks)
    for _ in range(task_count):
        transactions = q.get()
        q.task_done()
        ... rest of processing the same ...
    ... wait for all tasks to finish ...
```

This has two advantages.

First, you could define q as say `queue.Queue(maxsize=5)`.  Even though you rate limit the readers and writers, your readers could still get far ahead of your writers.  By forcing them to put their results into a blocking queue with limited size, the readers cannot get too far ahead of your writers.

You also no longer need to keep track of read tasks and write tasks separately.  You just need to keep them all in a single list, and `gather` them at the end.  With a little bit of rewriting you could even just use a `TaskGroup`.

Comment: Interesting, in this case, wouldn't I need to modify the part about creating and appending to `save_tasks` and then awaiting on them with `await asyncio.gather(*save_tasks) `?

Comment: You still need to keep track of the save tasks.  But you just want to know when they're all finished.